# action link mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How to open a new window with link to OutSide of MVC and take some Parameters while opening?

```
@Html.ActionLink("SomeTextForLink", "wwww.google.com", null, new { querystring values}, new { target ="_blank"})
```

I want to open something like `www.abc.com/contact.aspx?id=22` This is outside of MVC Page

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom helper for this:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString Link(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string baseUrl, object query, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
        anchor.SetInnerText(linkText);
        foreach (var item in new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes))
        {
            anchor.Attributes[item.Key] = item.Value as string;
        }

        var urlBuilder = new UriBuilder(baseUrl);
        var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        foreach (var item in new RouteValueDictionary(query))
        {
            values[item.Key] = item.Value as string;
        }
        urlBuilder.Query = values.ToString();
        anchor.Attributes["href"] = urlBuilder.ToString();

        return new HtmlString(anchor.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.Link(
    "SomeTextForLink",
    "http://www.google.com",
    new { param1 = "value1", param2 = "value2" }, 
    new { target = "_blank" }
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Generic way

Answer (score 6):

You cant use an ActionLink for that. ActionLinks are only for links to an Action inside your Application.

You can use a usual link

```
<a href="@string.Format("http://www.abc.com/contact.aspx?{0}", yourQueryString)" target="_blank">
    Link Text
</a>
```

Comment: Great answer. Follows my golden rule "As much HTML in HTML".